# Is Percival Graves using the Elder Wand in Fantastic Beasts?

Tags: character, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

At the end of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, we find out that

> Percival Graves = Gellert Grindelwald

We also know that Grindelwald had the Elder Wand, because Dumbledore had won it from him in a duel.

Is Percival Graves using the Elder Wand in *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* (2016)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.

[Percival Graves's wand](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Percival_Graves's_wand) looks like this:

[image]

Looks nothing like [Elder Wand](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Elder_Wand)

[image]

and why would Percival Graves take a risk using the Elder Wand, considering he wants to hide his original identity.

Comment: *"why would Percival Graves will take a risk to sue Elder Wand"* Nobody really knows about the Deathly Hallows, except in legend, certainly not enough to recognise the Elder Wand when in the presence of it (I suspect). But fair point, and good answer, thanks.

Comment: @GhotiandChips I will try to get with additional details later. ANyway nice question, I wish I had votes to spare.

Comment: Great question ! I didn't think of this.. but yes shouldn't  he be using the elder wand until his duel with Dumbledore? Hmm

Comment: Surely you all remember that Graves **gives** Creedence a necklace featuring the Deathly Hallows logo?

Comment: *Nobody really knows about the Deathly Hallows, except in legend, certainly not enough to recognise the Elder Wand when in the presence of it* -- Perhaps, but presumably MACUSA personnel know Graves well enough to recognize a want that wasn't his usual one.

Answer (score 3):

Well,  people might not reckognize the Elder Wand, but MACUSA people at  least would know the wand of the real Percival Graves. To use another wand would have been likely to bring about unnecessary questions ...

Comment: You are Mikmar, why not just log in with that account?

Answer (score 2):

At the very beginning of the movie, we see this king-size blast of magic.

Grindelwald used TEW when he had his original identity, but not while he disguised himself as Graves.

Comment: Any evidence to back this claim? Seems like pure speculation

Answer (score 2):

It seems pretty clear to me that Grindlewald has the wand the entire time.  It is simply masked with a charm to alter it's appearance. Why do people see this as a difficult thing to grasp, when Grindlewald himself was masked as Graves. I mean seriously, which do you think is harder to change the appearance of - a human being or a piece of wood?

Watch as he battles ALL the other aurors.  You'll notice an interesting fact, even with dozens of aurors, enough to destroy the largest obscurious in record.... NOT A SINGLE ATTACK penetrated Grindlewald's defenses.  No wand was able to defeat him.

And the writers did take this into account. How was Grindlewald defeated? Not by a wand, but by one of Newt Scamander's creatures, the " Swooping Evil".

It was very very clear to me, he was wielding the wand. Go back and look at all the wand duels and battles. Not a single one got past him.  And I also wager that Albus Dumbledore will defeat Grindlewald, and take ownership of the wand, not by dueling, nor by trickery or other means.  I suspect, Dumbledore will defeat Grindlewald with logic, reasoning, and love. And Grindlewald will hand over the wand, seeing that Dumbledore is in fact correct. And that Dumbledore will have won Grindlewald toward his view.

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved if you could include a quote from the film, or a statement from the director/producers, that supports your assumptions.