# How did Newt Scamander realize "someone's" real identity?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

In *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, Newt restrains Graves' movements with one of his friendly beasts and then proceeds to use the **Revelio** spell to... (spoiler)

> reveal Graves' true identity, who is actually Gellert Grindelwald.

My question is, **what gave him away**? How did Newt realize that man was not really Graves? I was thinking maybe the speech he gave matched...

> Grindelwald's ideas

...and also the power and skill he displayed whilst fighting the aurors. Does anyone have a better explanation for this? Also, as a curiosity, what did...

> Grindelwald

...do with the real Graves? Maybe something similar to what was done to Alastor Moody in *The Goblet of Fire*?

Comment: Good points on all counts. It's not much of an answer, so I am posting as a comment.

Comment: These are two separate questions.

Comment: Also, you can't be sure whether he used Polyjuice potion or not, and can therefore also not be sure whether there *is* a real Graves in the first place. In fact, for the reasons highlighted in [this question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63626/42655), evidence seems to suggest the opposite (Polyjuice Potion *wasn't* used).

Comment: Don't ask multiple question inside one body

Comment: @GhotiandChips, yes, there are two separate questions, but they are so connected that they might as well go together. In addition, I believe there is a real Graves, because he interacted with many people inside MACUSA.

Comment: @MatheusRotta I'm usually defending people for the thing I'm "attacking" you for now, which is allowing follow-up questions that answering the main question would lend to answering anyway, but this is not a case of that. I disagree that they are *so connected*, because one is asking about **Newt** and his ability to discern Graves' true identity, and the other question is asking about *Graves* and what happened to the "real" *Graves*. They are entirely separate topics, in my opinion, as someone who usually defends against what I'm arguing, but we can agree to disagree.

Comment: *[cont.]* Yes, you may *believe* that there is a real Graves, but it's not confirmed, yet, nor is there strong enough evidence to make the speculation sound, I don't think. Anyway, asking questions based on assumptions is tricky because your assumption may be false. I'm not trying to personally offend or spite you, I just genuinely think these are questions that deserve their own separate discussions, and that you made an assumption worth questioning and labelling as "speculation".

Comment: @GhotiandChips, I also believe that "these are questions that deserve their own separate discussions", that is why **the focus is on the first one**. I  hope someone will address that "second question" in a brand new question, that would be great, it would be a very useful discussion. What is wrong with speculation? Speculation, followed by research, usually renders good results.

Comment: @MatheusRotta It's not that there is something *wrong* with speculation, in and of itself, it's that asking a question that itself is *based* on assumption makes it problematic on a site like this, because potentially every answer will have to start by correcting your (potentially false) assumption. Example: **Q:** "How does Peter Pettigrew (aka Wormtail) die in *Deathly Hallows Part 1*?". **A:** "He doesn't die (in the movies), the last we see of him he is stunned by Dobby" || See how asking a question, based on a (potentially false) assumption is tricky?

Comment: *[cont.]* When you ask a question like "What happened to the *real* Graves?", you are leaving it up to chance that your question is based on a true assumption. Who's to say there *is* a real Graves. You could ask "Is there a *real* Graves?" or something along those lines.

Comment: There is a duplicate of this on Sci Fi at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/145920/4918 now.

Comment: @b_jonas, I was the first one to ask. I saw that you commented over there redirecting to this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think Graves said something along the lines of "for the greater good" which is the punchline and motto of you-know-who-2. The whole speech he gave was reeking of you-know-who-2's ideology

Also he attacked the ministry with quite expertise.. which ministry employee would do that?

The way he interacted with Credence and how he egged on Credence to unleash his power.

I'm sure with prior knowledge of the sort of person you-know-who-2 is.. it ticked off some alarm in Newt's head

Or he could just be absolutely lucky.

Comment: You-know-who-2! Nice, I enjoyed this name for him. The points you displayed are very coherent. But I was wondering if someone could give us something certain, maybe extracted from the book or from some interview with J.K.R.

Comment: Haha thank you ! @Matheus it sounded right for him ! :)

Answer (score 6):

The newspapers were filled with stories about Grindelwald. He is renowned or feared as a great wizard. All the magical community has Grindelwald on their minds.

I think the sheer scope and skill of his magic is what gives Newt the idea that Graves is Grindelwald. That is why Newt uses the Revelio spell.

Comment: If I edit do I need to make a comment so that the edit is noticed? Thanks!

Comment: What you did was fine.  It will also post on the main page again after an edit, so it's good :)

Answer (score 3):

I think, and this is just an idea, that fake Graves said something **when he was interviewing Newt** and maybe they both figured out that the other one knew.

It's the only idea I could come up with as Newt had very little contact with the man before hand, apart from seeing him in Tina's workspaces.

Comment: Could you add the conversations from the movie to support your answer?

Answer (score 3):

A lot of people have suggested a few different ideas for how Newt discovered about -you know who 2-'s reveal. But baring in mind this wizard in question was a masterful wizard with charms (could turn invisible using charms at 17 so it's more probable to use that rather than Polyjuice potion) it's more likely something to do with Newt's abilities rather than -you know who's- mistakes.
Reminder Newt works with some peculiar animals/creatures as well as having experience with evil beasts such as Dragons and Obscurials. It's probably something he noticed from -you know who's- actions and speech. Plus -you know who- was very well known in Europe and not in America. We don't know if they could have met before. For all we know or Dumbledore told him about -YKW-. In truth

I think the power too. Queenie couldn't read his mind and open his door, while being able to fight the Aurors (while using wandless magic I may add).

The real Graves is probably dead. I don't think -YKW- would have bothered to carry baggage while in the USA with his lifestyle. Plus Graves was head of Security and high up in MACUSA. Too dangerous to him to be left alive.

Just my thoughts!