# What was the method behind Graves' appearance?

Tags: character, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

I've seen *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* but I can't recall if I assumed that Grindelwald had been using Polyjuice in order to take on Graves' appearance, a la Barty Crouch and Mad Eye Moody appearance, or if this was factually confirmed in the movie. Do we know it was definitely Polyjuice?

I want to know if Graves' could appear in the sequel so is he alive in order for the Polyjuice production to continue or is he likely murdered.

Comment: Title spoilers!

Comment: @OrangeDog fixed now

Comment: Highly related: [How can a witch/wizard disguise themselves, excluding Polyjuice Potion?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63626/49)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in detail over on Science Fiction & Fantasy in [**this answer**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145434/how-did-this-fantastic-beasts-character-disguise-themselves).

Essentially...

> **Through an advanced spell**
>
> J.K. Rowling answered this question in the FAQ of her new website.
>
> > **Why did ‘revelio’ undo the effects of Polyjuice Potion?**
> >
> > It didn’t. Grindelwald’s Transfiguration surpasses that of most wizards, so he used a spell, not a potion, to take on the appearance of Percival Graves.
> >     <sub>[J.K. Rowling's new website - FAQ](http://jkrowling.com/welcome-to-my-new-website/)</sub>

More information and older (obsolete) answer at the link above.

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't know about JK's personal website off to snoop through its contents.